# How to make object persist in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos

When running a ruby script, is it possible to have objects persist in memory over multiple invocations?

```
ruby run.rb
```

Working in OSX.

Comment: What kind of object? What kind of persistence?

Comment: It holds stock market data. It loads the data from a file and processes it. It takes a long time to process (perhaps 95%) of the processing in the application.

Comment: So you want to memoize the result of that expensive computation? I'd say to use an in-memory cache for that, like @Mori recommended in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cache for that, e.g. memcached with [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) or redis with various [redis clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Redis).

Answer (score 2):

## Marshaling

Check out the [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) library.

`Marshal.dump` lets you serialize the data in your object and save it to a file.

The next time your program starts, you can check for the existence of that file and use `Marshal.load` to take that data and recreate your object.

Comment: Yes, thought of that, but I have many objects and they can have different states, so that solution adds complexity...

Comment: It loads data and processes the data. But I don't have a way of tracking what is loaded and what is processed. I can add that but it increases complexity...